# Javascript appendChild Issues

Tags: javascript, appendchild

This function occurs when a thumbnail image is clicked; which uses the thumbnail's ID to get the ID of a div ("item"+f) that holds an image and some text, then paste it the "display" div.

The issue is that I want to clear out the display div each time it's clicked so only one div is displayed, but I'm having trouble doing that using 'appendChild's (which I'm told is recommended over using innerHTML). My current solution below is attempting to take what's in the display div and append it to a hidden div so it can be used again later, but doesn't seem to be working out.

displayimage and removeimage are divs that I'm just using to hold the divs I'm moving around... which doesn't seem to make sense but it seems to work better. If you can see anything wrong with my process or how to use 'appendChild' better that would be helpful.

```
function thumbclick(clickedimage) {
var f = clickedimage.charAt(clickedimage.length - 1);
displayimage = document.getElementById("item"+f);
removeimage = document.getElementById("display").getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
document.getElementById("galleryimages").appendChild(removeimage);
document.getElementById("display").appendChild(displayimage);
}
```

I often get "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8", which when researched seems to be that I'm not appending the right type of elements... but I'm just appending divs to divs?

Edit: Sorry for not posting enough detail; it seems CN Kanode in the comments has my problem, the display div starts out empty and so there is nothing to remove. Thanks!

Comment: Which line gets the error?

Comment: Can you show the HTML structure as well?

Comment: According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107), that is not an error that can be thrown by `appendChild()`. Are you sure this is the line the error is on?

Comment: Need more info.  One guess would be that it will error if there is no child div currently in your display div.

Comment: Are `displayimage` and `removeimage` actually nodes? Or are they `null`?

Comment: The removeimage line gets the error, and I'm not entirely sure what you mean with display/removeimage, they're divs and I'm setting a value for them... the HTML structure is really as simple as it sounds, just a div for thumbnails, then display, then the hidden galleryimages. It may be that it is an error because there is no div the first run through, that does seem likely actually...

Comment: Yes, CM Kanode is correct, the display div is empty to begin with and that caused the problem; sorry for not providing enough detail.

Answer (score -2):

The following code should have the same effect as yours, only using jQuery, which certainly hasn't issues manipulating DOM:

```
function thumbclick(clickedimage) {
    var f = clickedimage.charAt(clickedimage.length - 1);
    var removeimage = $('#display div');
    $('#galleryimages').append(removeimage);
    removeimage.remove();
    $('#display div').append($('item'+f));
}​
```

EDIT: You'll need to include this in the `<head>` of your html to get jQuery working:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: -1 **The DOM API** has no issues manipulating the DOM, either.